# Is No Man's Sky actually multiplayer?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've heard claims that the game is multiplayer, but the universe is so huge you will almost certainly never encounter another player.

That seems unlikely.  It's a *lot* of work to make a game multiplayer, so I doubt they would go through all that effort for a feature they didn't expect anyone to ever actually use.

So, what happens when two players are on the same planet?  Can they see/interact/communicate with each other?

Comment: Sean Murray talks about it [in this interview](https://youtu.be/F6mO6YTvjVw?t=6m20s). As he says, NMS is multiplayer in the sense that multiple players are in a shared universe and there are mechanisms in place so that people could play together, but [space is big](http://hitchhikersguidequotes.tumblr.com/post/13945214509/space-is-big-really-big-you-just-wont-believe), so don't expect to just be able to meet up with your bro for keg stands or whatever. (Whether that feature works or not is another matter.)

Comment: When in doubt, look at something that's moving and hit pause.

Comment: There's several answers in here but there is simply no way to know this right now. If we were to base it off what the developers said, then there absolutely is _supposed_ to be multiplayer. They stated this several times publicly. Having said that, based on a single _alleged_ interaction by two players, there is no multiplayer. The servers were known to be having issues, as that was on launch day or a day or two after, so again, there is no way to tell presently.

Comment: I think a better way to ask this question is: "Does NMS run without an internet connections? If yes, what features do you lose? What information is transmitted over the connection?"

Comment: So essentially their multiplyer is like Spore's Multiplayer?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

## Update:

As of the "[1.5 NEXT](https://www.nomanssky.com/next-update/)" update, there is 4-player multiplayer.  Players can see each others' buildings/ships, interact and trade with each other, and fight together.  Quests are still separate.

If you're here to see the list of all the ways the players were lied to about multiplayer, see this answer's history.

Comment: As of [7/24/2018](https://www.nomanssky.com/next-update/) You can now play with other players

Comment: This answer is outdated as of update 1.5 "NEXT". You now can see up to 4 players and interact with them (see them, their ship, their vehicles, their base, trade with them or even shoot at them).

Answer (score 67):

> ## TL;DR
>
> **NO** in a sense that, you can't do PvP, You can't see other players, You can't explore with your buddies, etc, etc. and **YES** in a sense of that there is an online function to open your Galactic Map and Scan here and there, and actually see traces of other players, and by traces I mean stuff they have maybe dropped in a planet, or creatures they named or planets

---

This is coming directly from Sean Murray (Game Director for *Hello Games*®):

> To be super clear - No Man's Sky is not a multiplayer game. Please don't go in looking for that experience.

Twitter Link:
https://twitter.com/NoMansSky/status/762688708764135425

---

#### No There is Not.

For the past few days I have been encountering people wanting to know a definite answer for this, and the definite answer is that there is actually ***NO*** such thing as multiplayer, when I first came in here I barely knew about the game and I know I shouldn't had provided an answer where I have limited knowledge to, however my impulse in wanting to help everyone seemed to be the motivation in getting involved in this, and because games are part of my passion as well.

Now I have separated myself in the past few hours just to purely do research based on this subject, And let me just begin with, Even though the Developer mentioned and could almost had swear before the heavens that the game indeed was gonna bring some "form" of Multiplayer capabilities, it was totally being misunderstood and misinterpreted by many people, Now I have came up with the conclusion that, *NO*, there is no Multiplayer in this game, basically the developer himself said it in many interviews, that if you would go with your friend and maybe gather in some point, the probabilities of you seeing him and vice-versa are extremely narrowed down, next to null.

Because of the massive procedural settings the game brings, Therefore, by the time you both try to accomplish such mission, it could have been ages already, and either you or your friend will drop off from keep on working on such thing.

And even though and surprisingly enough two players have actually done that, Take a look at this article backing up my statement:

> ...Throughout the stream, viewers have seen the players stand in the same space stations, speak with the same planetary denizens and stop by identical waypoints, **only to never actually see each other**. Also of note is that one player's planet is experiencing daytime while the other is venturing during the night... 
>   [Article by Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/2016/8/9/12417202/no-mans-sky-no-multiplayer-twitch-stream)

Even though there was an update to the article, it still remains that it's not possible that there is multiplayer on the game... Not to mention that you can actually pause the game, everything stops moving, creatures, even ships flying by, doesn't that gives you a sense of a static feeling?

#### Yes There is.

Also this is where most people are getting confused, because *Yes* while there are some multiplayer features built-into the game, like with many other Singleplayer games, they are *ONLY* and strictly dedicated in helping the player to find traces of other players, like for example if they dropped something in a planet, and you later come in, you can see the dropped equipment, and if you go to a planet you will see if it was discovered by someone already, see creatures named by other players etc, etc. and there is no motivation behind the developers whatsoever to change that AFAIK.

Answer (score 18):

According to the [Steam Store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/275850/) it is single player. Your universe is occupied by one human player, and that is you. Your universe is informed by the actions taken by other players in theirs, mostly discoveries and naming of galaxies and points of interest.

I have seen no evidence that you actually can interact with or even see the avatars of other players.

Comment: Note that the [PSN Store page](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/games/no-man's-sky/cid=UP2034-CUSA04841_00-NMSDIGITAL000001) also lists it as "1 player"

Comment: The reason so many people think it's possible to meet other players is that a ton of the pre-release information implied it is, though I don't think they ever said it outright.  **Edit** Actually, they said it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0uYnwqlslU&feature=youtu.be&t=1m32s)

Comment: [Here's a picture of the box, showing that they covered the online box art with a sticker](http://imgur.com/a/YMS1O)

Answer (score 4):

[Multiplayer is now an option with the NEXT update.](https://www.nomanssky.com/next-update/)

While the campaign is effectively a single player game with friends, you can now play alongside your friends, trade resources, build together, and share eachothers equipment.

You are in a server with 16 players.  Up to 4 players can be in a party.  You can see the other players in your party, but everyone else will still appear as "glitches".

Answer (score -1):

There is not multiplayer in the sense that you are thinking.
This was one feature that many players asked about and the developers originally denied, but later gave more cryptic answers to.

Although many of us would love to meet up with our friends, fly through space, and explore/build on planets we discover, this feature is **not** in the game.  I'll look for the old interview by Sean Murray that I read when I first saw that this wasn't going to be implemented.

Unfortunately, because No Mans Sky does feature a method of naming planets/wildlife for other players to see, Hello Games later began to give vague answers regarding multiplayer which left a lot of players thinking it was still going to be implemented.  Hello Games considers this a form of multiplayer.

TLDR: You can't play with other players.

Answer (score -5):

**No mans Sky does have multiplayer**

*If you look at this reddit thread* : https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4wyb7g/psytokat_and_thesadcactus_tried_to_meet_up_in/ the comments talk about different lobbies that the game has and the two players that met just happened to be in different lobbies. So technically it is possible to meet other players, but the lobby system makes it so incredibly difficult because even if you manage to find another person they have a low chance of actually being in your lobby.

Comment: That is just a guess some players made, it appears to be incorrect

Comment: Ah my bad then, I thought someone had a link to an interview with Sean.