# How long does it take to get to the center of the Galaxy?

Tags: no-mans-sky

After finishing the Atlas path I am now trying to get to the Center of the Galaxy but it seems to take an awful long time to get there. According to the game it will still take 175869 light years to get there? At the pace I am playing this will take longer than a year I think to get there... Or are there some black holes that will make a huge difference, so far it doesn't seem to help me much further at all...

Also is this different for everyone depending on where they start in the universe?
Will I be able to meet other players as well there?

Comment: This all really depends on the player and how much time you spend trying to get there. There is no concrete answer for this. It could take 30 hours or 300 hours depending on what you do, how much of your stuff breaks and how long it takes to find resources to fix it.

Comment: "Will I be able to meet other players as well there?" No, NMS is not multiplayer. You will never be able to meet other players, period. [See this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/280918/145980) for more details.

Comment: Black holes vary in how far you travel when you go through them.  They're better than using the hyperdrive but the variety in distance makes it impossible to say how much they help.  Also, everyone starts at a totally random location, so one persons experience will not reflect your own.

Comment: @Archer Also just to note, sometimes Black Holes will break parts of the equipment on your ship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time it takes to get to the centre of the Galaxy is different for everyone as everyone starts in different parts of the Galaxy. The time it took the first to reach the centre on ps4 was a little over a week I believe, but that was rushing through the game upgrading his hyperdrive and gathering resources for warp cells...